# Cannot select path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I am re-designing a small shampoo bag package for a company using the old design format by the former designer. But there are paths that I could not select, and if I use Ctrl + Y they are not visible anymore. Does anyone know what these paths are ?[image: Paths I couldn't select]

Comment: Looks like a **brush** applied to the path possibly. Just guessing really.

Comment: Could be a pattern or maybe some effect, we'll need to see the layer panel, and if you can select the object with these "paths" inside, you can check the aspect panel to see what is applied to it.

Comment: I think there is a pattern on the background rectangle, then there are 2 rectangles covering the background.